# E-mail intercepting and blocking for newsletter test

Tags: email, smtp

I am searching for a tool that would let me intercept and block outgoing e-mail messages from my computer.

Ideally I would be able to see the intended recipients as well as the e-mail message that would be sent.

Is there any software available that can accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ues a local smtp server like [FakeSMTP](http://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) to do this.

> FakeSMTP is a Free Fake SMTP Server with GUI for testing emails in
>   applications easily. It is written in Java. Configure your application
>   to use "localhost" as your SMTP server, and all emails will be
>   intercepted and displayed in this software.